# I can't save the text entered to the UITableView when I run the app in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and testing it on an iPhone 5C. 
I'm following the Ray Wenderlich tutorial "First Core Data App Using Swift."
[This is the Ray Wenderlich tutorial link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift) I also had this problem when I followed another tutorial. What basically happens is that I can see the table view lines and then I click Add on the top (bar bell item) and then I enter the string I want displayed on that line and hit Save and the data won't save. I will simply return to an empty Table View. [image: Here's the table view after I entered the text and hit save. The text won't appear.] [image: This is the save screen on my iPhone]

> // //  ViewController.swift //  HitList // //  Created by Faigy Mayer
>   on 12/17/14. //  Copyright (c) 2014 Faigy Mayer. All rights reserved.
>   //
>
> import UIKit
>
> class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
> var names = [String]()
> @IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {
>     var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New name",
>         message: "Add a new name",
>         preferredStyle: .Alert)
>
>     let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
>         style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
>
>             let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
>             self.names.append(textField.text)
>             self.tableView.reloadData()
>     }
>
>     let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
>         style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
>     }
>
>     alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
>         (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
>     }
>
>     alert.addAction(saveAction)
>     alert.addAction(cancelAction)
>
>     presentViewController(alert,
>         animated: true,
>         completion: nil)
> }
>
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
>     title = "\"The List\""
>     tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
>         forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
> }
>
> override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
>     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> // MARK: UITableViewDataSource
> func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
>     numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
>         return names.count
> }
>
> func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
>     cellForRowAtIndexPath
>     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
>
>         let cell =
>         tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
>             as UITableViewCell
>
>         cell.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]
>
>         return cell
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Add  your Save button event here in question

Comment: Are you trying to actually use core data like the tutorial title suggests?

Comment: @meghan66: Try using breakpoint to Save button event and also at cellforrowatindexpath and check your value is getting stored properly or not.

Comment: @Mrunal, if you look at the code, the save event is a UIAlertAction in an IBAction function.

Comment: @meghan66 Yes I show that, but is it getting updated array, can you check all objects + last added object there?

Comment: @Mrunal, how do I do that? The array is not updating when I enter it on my iPhone. How do I "check all objects + last added object?" Thanks!

Comment: @meghan66 : That's what i was saying, your code is correct for tableview stuffs, but problem is with alertview and data storage.

Comment: @mrunal, Can you tell me how to fix that? What do I google to find out what is wrong? I mean, according to the tutorial everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a delegate and datasource, simply select your table view in interface builder, and ctrl-drag to your view controller, like this:
[image: interface builder]
and then a dialog appears, which you simple select datasource and/or delegate:
[image: select]

Answer (score 0):

Most common, you are missing the delegate and datasource for your tableview. Also try to log your datasource after add action. If it contains elements, you are missing the delegate and source....

Comment: how do I add the delegate and datasource?